# Creating buttons dynamically on Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically create buttons upon the click of another button using Angular 2.

The basic idea is that upon the click the original button an array will be returned. Then, for each element within the array I need to create a new button.

If anyone could point me in the right direction for this I'd really really appreciate it.

Thanks! Hope you're having a lovely day :)

Comment: I dont understand what you try to do. Give more infos, provide code and tell what you tried if you want an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> template

```
<button (click)="pushToArray()">Main Button</button>
<!-- Dynamic Arrays -->
<ng-container *ngIf="dynArr.length > 0">
 <button *ngFor="let i of dynArr" (click)="buttonClicked(i) [innerHTML]="'Dynamic Button: ' + i"></button>
</ng-container>
```

> component

```
dynArr = [];
nextNum = 0;

pushToArray() {
 this.dynArr.push(nextNum);
 nextNum++;
}

buttonClicked(index: number) {
 // logic for each dynamic button click;
 // buttons distinguishable by 'index' value
}
```

It's not an ideal code to follow. Can probably refactor if you can specify what exactly you wanna do with it. But given the details of your requirement, this should do the job.